# WPF Control disappears when is is animated with DoubleAnimation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, doubleanimation

I have a TextBox(toAnimate) and an Button(toClick).
When i click the button, the TextBox disappears.
But it should move on the X Position 20 units.

What did i do wrong?

```
//double left = Canvas.GetLeft(toAnimate); Returned wrong value.
TranslateTransform tanl = new TranslateTransform();
Vector pos = VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset(toAnimate);
double left = pos.X;
toAnimate.RenderTransform = tanl;
DoubleAnimation doua = new DoubleAnimation((left + 20), left, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
tanl.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, doua);
```

Comment: at the top you have this line: Canvas.GetLeft(toAnimate); . seems like you do nothing with the returned value?

Comment: Shouldn't you animate Canvas.Left instead of TranslateTransform.XProperty?

Comment: Canvas.LeftProperty is not is not the right property.